# Datastore query inconsistencies

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-console

Why would the following query builder work in the Google cloud console but not programmatically?
[image]

And here is my query from my cpp program

```
Query: kind {
  name: "db-wahalao-users"
}
filter {
  composite_filter {
    op: AND
    filters {
      property_filter {
        property {
          name: "displayName.username"
        }
        op: EQUAL
        value {
          string_value: "Obasi"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
order {
  property {
    name: "createdAt"
  }
  direction: DESCENDING
}
```

The right permissions are used, I use a service account. Also, when I do a general query without filtering, I do get the right results. But this indexing by displayName.username does not seem to work only in the program code. Or let me say, it has worked once or twice. Nothing makes sense here.

Comment: What's the error message?  It looks like you should have a composite index on `displayName.username` & `createdAt`, and that you should use a property_filter instead of a composite_filter for your single filter.

Comment: I have the index. I don't think it has to do with the index because if it was an index problem, the Google Cloud console execution would have resulted in an error. I have a suspicion that it has to do with my indexes. There is this extra added property when one creates an index __name__: desc or asc. When I create the index through the Firebase console, it has a value of desc, but creating the datastore index results in that being asc. I don't have any idea how to correct that though. At least, that is the only discrepancy I can find with my implementation. I am using datastore in native mode.

Comment: Without any error message, it's not obvious what problem you are encountering.

Comment: Well that’s the think. No error is reported. I think the problem is the Google cloud cpp datastore api has a problem when filter querying datastore in native mode.